# Three nonlinear equations with three unknowns - how can be solved with f.solve?

Tags: python, numpy, nonlinear-optimization

I am new to Python. I am sharing a code snippet which is a part of a code to read data from a file and make the needed calculations. I have 3 nonlinear eqs with 3 unknowns. I wrote the following code to solve it, but the code gives me an error of:

```
File "<ipython-input-46-bc67ad1b6153>", line 4
    eq2 = (y/(1-y) - (5/(8*np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 - (np.cot(z)))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not think the syntax is wrong, but I am not sure if this kind of solution works in my case. Also, my variable "x" should be in the rage between 1/4 and 1/3

My code:

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(vars):
    x, y, z = vars
    eq1 = (x/(1-x) - (5/(8*np.pi*np.sin(z)**2) * (1 + 4*(np.tan(z))
    eq2 = (y/(1-y) - (5/(8*np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 - (np.cot(z)))
    eq3 = np.tan(z) - ((1-x) / 3 * (1+y))
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]

x, y,z =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1, 1))

print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: issues: 1) cot does not exist use `1/np.tan(z) ` 2) you forgot some parenthesis in eq1 and eq2. 3) your initial guess causes singularity in eq1 and eq2 x/(1-x) ->1/0

Comment: @UlisesBussi thanks for the reply. I am afraid I did not quite understand  "your initial guess causes singularity in eq1 and eq2 x/(1-x) ->1/0 ".You mean, I should have a statement for x, y being different than 1, right?

Comment: hi i posted an aswer, your initial guess or initial condition are the values that you propose as solution for the equation system (in this case you proposed `(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)`). That's the values that you are using in fsolve

Answer (score 1):

I encountered some errors in your code:

1. there's no `np.cot` function you maybe want to use `1/np.tan(z)` in equation 3.
2. you forgot some parentheses (`eq1` and `eq2`) so it will never work (I might put some but i'm just guessing. you might to correct that part
3. your initial guess `(1,1,1)` causes a singularity in `eq1` and `eq2`

so here a proposal (check parentheses)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(vars):
    x, y, z = vars
    eq1 = (x/(1-x)) - (5/(8*np.pi*np.sin(z)**2)) * (1 + 4*(np.tan(z)))
    eq2 = (y/(1-y)) - (5/(8*np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 - (1/np.tan(z)))
    eq3 = np.tan(z) - ((1-x) / 3 * (1+y))
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]

x, y,z =  fsolve(equations, (2, 2, 2))

print(x, y, z)
#prints: 1.4489745262423956 26.230116359918174 1.8114278561902486
```

Comment: Now I get it, But the thing is I have a constraint that a should be  in-between 1/4 and 1/3, I guess I cannot use it as a initial condition for f.solve? Also, the code will make calculations for 14 different values, (from data table)

Comment: I think that you can not put constraints in fsolve... But if you're lookin a solution in that range then try a initial guess inside it (it could get the result you want if it exists). if not you'll have to use another method. If you have a data table then create combinations as tuples and pass it to fsolve

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong number of parenthesis in several lines of code. Also there is no `np.cot()`, use `1 / np.tan()` instead. Fixed working code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsMgDIbvPMV/JGnSKM0mVZP2JFUPUUdUpAUokCrk5TM7YT1tFjLyb/sD26V4t6ZbVz066yPMNLqEPsA4kaWxj3cxeDsi3LRLR@uiHvWikPNDsN9PJb7UAPWY@qitCfLZ@1B8CJDNFVKFBZ9gcZPUo6VQzmggW9SYC3LyncMzSnr76PR@B23kUqAscSLP1Qe87anYc4osI0@MTL/I9C/yZsPWt@Nqds1fvI54L5nrZFvTRxt0W@ch5Uqv4uQNLjRUxd9g112F2ObmsfOG5Gs7FbVX4EMI4bw2UeYtFWJdfwA)

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def equations(vars):
    x, y, z = vars
    eq1 = (x / (1 - x) - (5 / (8 * np.pi * np.sin(z) ** 2) * (1 + 4 * np.tan(z))))
    eq2 = (y / (1 - y) - (5 / (8 * np.pi * np.cos(z))) * (1 - (1 / np.tan(z))))
    eq3 = np.tan(z) - ((1-x) / 3 * (1+y))
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3]

x, y,z =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1, 1))

print(x, y, z)
```

Output:

```
1.0 1.0 1.0
```